# Sublime text 3+ LaTeXtools + SumatraPDF, Pdf file doesn't popup after compiling

Tags: sublime-text, sumatrapdf, latextools

I am using Sublime text 3 + LaTeXtools + SumatraPDF (Windows 10), I can successfully compile my .tex file, but the PDF previewer(SumatraPDF) doesn't popup automatically. I need to open the .pdf file manually.

My settings:
1: "sumatra": "", and the location of "SumatraPDF.exe" is already on my PATH.
2: In LaTeXTools.sublime-settings, 
I set "keep_focus": false,
      "forward_sync": false,
the pdf previewer still doesn't show up.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks.
Nic

Comment: I think I know the reason, my pdf previewer does popup simply because my .tex file have error....

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what you said in the comment. If there's an error, the PDF won't be automatically opened. This is because errors almost always mean the PDF file wasn't changed, and often that it's completely blank. You can, however, use LaTeXTools view command `C-l,v` or `C-l,j`  (which syncs to the corresponding line in the file) to open the PDF anyways.